# Why is my resnet50 model in Keras not converging?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, resnet, transfer-learning

I am currently trying to classify integrated circuits in defect and non defect images. I already tried VGG16 and InceptionV3 and got really good results for both (95% validation accuracy and low val loss). Now I wanted to try resnet50 but my model is not converging. Its accuracy is at 95 % too but the validation loss keeps increasing while the val acc gets stuck at 50 %.

This is my script so far:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf

class ResNet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_width, self.img_height = 224, 224  # Dimensions of cropped image
        self.classes_num = 2  # Number of classifications

        # Training configurations
        self.epochs = 32
        self.batch_size = 16  # Play with this to determine number of images to train on per epoch
        self.lr = 0.0001

    def build_model(self, train_path):
        train_data_path = train_path
        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, validation_split=0.25)

        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_path,
            target_size=(self.img_height, self.img_width),
            color_mode="rgb",
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            class_mode='categorical',
            subset='training')

        validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_path,
            target_size=(self.img_height, self.img_width),
            color_mode="rgb",
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            class_mode='categorical',
            subset='validation')

        # create the base pre-trained model
        base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=    (self.img_height, self.img_width, 3))

        # add a global spatial average pooling layer
        x = base_model.output
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
        # let's add a fully-connected layer
        x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
        #x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
        # and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 200 classes
        predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

        # this is the model we will train
        model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

        # first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
        # i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
        for layer in base_model.layers:
            layer.trainable = True

        # compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non-trainable)
        opt = Adam(self.lr)  # , decay=self.INIT_LR / self.NUM_EPOCHS)
        model.compile(opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

        # train the model on the new data for a few epochs
        from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('resnetModel.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)

        early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=16, verbose=1, mode='auto')
        hist = model.fit_generator(steps_per_epoch=self.batch_size, generator=train_generator,
                               validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=self.batch_size, epochs=self.epochs,
                               callbacks=[checkpoint, early])

        plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'])
        plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
        plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
        plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
        plt.title("model accuracy")
        plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
        plt.xlabel("Epoch")
        plt.legend(["Accuracy", "Validation Accuracy", "loss", "Validation Loss"])
        plt.show()

        plt.figure(1)

import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = ResNet()
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
    x.build_model("C:/Users/but/Desktop/dataScratch/Train")
```

And this is the training of the model

[image]

What could be the reason for resnet to fail but for vgg and inception to work?
Do I have any mistakes in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for the code, I don't see any mistakes that might affect the training process.

```
# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 200 classes
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Those lines are a bit suspicious. But it seems that the typo is on the comment, so it should be okay.

```
# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
```

These are suspicious too. If you want to freeze the ResNet-50's layers, what you need to do is

```
...
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(self.img_height, self.img_width, 3))
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
...
```

But it turned out that `layer.trainable = True` was actually your intention, so it wouldn't matter either.

First of all, if you are using the same code which you used for training VGG16 and Inception V3, it is unlikely that the code is the problem.

Why don't you check following susceptible reasons?

- The model may be too small/big that it underfits/overfits. (Number of Parameters)
- The model may need more time to converge. (Training for more epochs)
- The ResNet may not be suited for this classification.
- Pretrained weights that you used may not be suited for this classification.
- The learning rate may be too small/big.
- etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
What do you mean by the model may be too small/big?
With more time to converge you mean more epochs? And what is with the learning rate? Should I change it because it may be too small?
Yeah I thought of the weights not being suited but then I find it odd that inception and vgg are working.

Comment: @NECben067 Yes, by "more time to converge" I mean "more epochs". And by "the model may be too small/big" I am saying about the number of parameters. (I don't think that this is the problem in this case since you are doing a transfer learning, but who knows.) You may try different learning rates too.

Comment: Ok I will try it out now. Is it still Transfer Learning when I set all layers as trainable?
I thought of maybe freezing first x layers and train last y layers but I don't exactly know which layers to freeze and which to train.

Also I get this Warning:

UserWarning: The output shape of `ResNet50(include_top=False)` has been changed since Keras 2.2.0.
  warnings.warn('The output shape of `ResNet50(include_top=False)` ' 

But could this be an issue I don't know.

Comment: @NECben067 I am pretty sure that it is still a Transfer Learning. You might also try adding another fully-connected layer at the end. I am not sure how to freeze first x layers and train last y either, but you can easily find how to do those things by googling. I think that UserWarning is not a problem.

Comment: @NECben067 I think `layer.trainable = True` is not what you want. Try removing that `layer.trainable = True` for loop. And write it just under the `base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=    (self.img_height, self.img_width, 3))` but this time with `layer.trainable = False`.

Comment: I increased the number of epochs to 128 now and it got a val acc of 99% and val decent val loss as well, thanks for your help! :)

And yes, one might think that freezing x layers and train the others might be written somewhere on the web but I really searched for it long and didn't find anything suitable :D

I never thought of increasing the number of epochs because it got worse results on the other architectures.

Comment: yes I tried it with trainable = false but I think the problem is that the imagenet classes doesn't fit for my problem. In my case I have integrated circuits that can be defect or non defect as mentioned earlier. The defect ones have scratches or cracks on the surface but look very similar to the non defects. That's why I try to train them with doing more fine tuning.